# GXT Grid ValueProvider / PropertyAccess for a Map<K,V> Datastore?

Tags: gxt, datastore

Rather than using Bean model objects, my data model is built on Key-Value pairs in a HashMap container.

Does anyone have an example of the GXT's Grid ValueProvider and PropertyAccess that will work with a underlying Map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't have one built in, but it is easy to build your own. Check out this blog post for a similar way of thinking, especially the ValueProvider section: http://www.sencha.com/blog/building-gxt-charts

The purpose of a `ValueProvider` is to be a simple reflection-like mechanism to read and write values in some object. The purpose of `PropertyAccess<T>` then is to autogenerate some of these value/modelkey/label provider instances based on getters and setters as are found on Java Beans, a very common use case. It doesn't have much more complexity than that, it is just a way to simply ask the compiler to do some very easy boilerplate code for you.

As that blog post shows, you can very easily build a ValueProvider just by implementing the interface. Here's a quick example of how you could make one that reads a `Map<String, Object>`. When you create each instance, you tell it which key are you working off of, and the type of data it should find when it reads out that value:

```java
public class MapValueProvider<T> implements 
            ValueProvider<Map<String, Object>, T> {
    private final String key;
    public MapValueProvider(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public T getValue(Map<String, Object> object) {
        return (T) object.get(key);
    }
    public void setValue(Map<String, Object> object, T value) {
        object.put(key, value);
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

You then build one of these for each key you want to read out, and can pass it along to `ColumnConfig` instances or whatever else might be expecting them.

The main point though is that `ValueProvider` is just an interface, and can be implemented any way you like.